# Is it possible to run PIC16F88 at 3V?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pic

I have notice that PICs have the 16F88 and 16LF88 version, after some researching i tought the LF is for chips that work at 3.3V, in other places it says i can still use the 16F88 at 3.3V, the datasheet clearly says :
**Wide operating voltage range: 2.0V to 5.5V**

Can i power my 16F88 with CR32-3V battery and will the I/Os work at the supplied 3V voltage ?

Comment: If the data sheet says 2.0V to 5.5V then 2.0V to 5.5V it is.  The data sheet is LAW.  Ignore EVERYTHING else.

Comment: -1 How is 3.3 V not obviously and clearly within "2.0V to 5.5V"?  What else can the datasheet say to make this any clearer?

Comment: Olin Lathrop it is not that obvious for example about the output I/Os, if you don't want to help you don't need to write ofensive answers, just go and play sugar rush.

Comment: Don't forget, that CR batteries have 3.0V when they are full. Empty battery is about 2.0V. Look at discharge characteristics in datasheet: http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/cr2032.pdf

Comment: @Electropepper It's pretty obvious if you read the electrical specifcations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have stated, the datasheet is indeed the LAW, but *only the part that show the operating conditions*. You are justified in distrusting broad claims in the text part of the datasheet, especially those on the first page.

For the 16(L)F88 the operating conditions clearly state the allowed power supply voltages and clock frequency combinations.

[image]

As you can see, the non-L version is NOT guarateed to operate below 4.0 V. The L version is, but not up to the full 20 MHz that the non-L version can run. The 'sales speak summary' of this is that the 16F88/LF88 can run up to 20 MHz and can run on voltages 2.0 - 5.5V. Yeah, but *that does not refer to the same part, and certainly not at the same time*.

That said, when you grab a 16F88 or 16LF88 you can probably operate it (in your 20C lab environment) according to either graph, and maybe even run it at 20 MHz at 2.0V. Remember that there is never a guarantee that a part won't operate outside its documented normal operating conditions. But you do so at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

(As an extended comment rather than an answer, but I'd like to share)

Wouter is absolutely correct here. It is normal for datasheets to show the broadest ranges on the first page. Microchip have many PIC microcontrollers and variations within each family. So when one datasheet covers a few variations, especially LF vs F, you will see a summary covering all variations on the front page.

"Wide operating voltage range: 2.0 - 5.5V". "ECIO up to 20MHz". As Wouter says this does *not* refer to the same part at the same time! Unsuspecting newcomers might not be aware of this.

This isn't unique to microcontrollers. Mosfet datasheets do it all the time with the front page saying "threshold voltage only 1.1V!". Yes, but at what current? Scan down the page, look at the graphs, ah ha! 1.1V at 250uA! That may not be a useful current for your application!

Part of being a professional engineer is asking these questions:

- What is my variation (temperature, voltage, current, frequency)
- Do all the *specific* parts I've chosen operate within these parameters
- If the specific ones do but the general ones don't, *note that on the schematic and BOM*.

This is more obvious for components such as capacitors, where a 4V part in a 12V circuit will result in smoke (and litigation) but other components are more subtle. Always, always specify.

I made this mistake 2 months ago in an end of year consortium product demo with senior execs. I knew the operating parameters of the PIC16(L)F88, I had referred to the graphs, I was operating at 3.3V but I didn't note it on the schematic and I put an L88 in the socket in the last few test days before the demo.

It programmed and verified fine and tested fine and worked fine but I went slightly pale later when I realised what happened. If I had been running at more than 4MHz and less than 3.5V, and less than 20 degrees, it might have failed. But, then as Wouter says, it might never have failed: "you do so at your own risk".

At least I didn't ship 10 million of them. Then you get fired :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the datasheet says 2.0-5.5V then you are near the middle of the range with 3.0V you should be fine.  Best way to know, build one and see.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work, however, look in the datasheet for the maximum safe operating speed for the micro-controller running at 3.0V. Usually the case is that the maximum safe operating speed decreases as you lower the voltage powering the device.

Comment: Agreed, I seem to remember this is the main difference with LF parts, the charts for frequency versus voltage are different and allow the LF series to run at higher frequencies at lower voltages.